# Arbitrary spatial rotation (Euler/Quaternion) using Proj transformation

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, proj

I’m a geologist who is working with paleogeographic reconstructions (see example [here](https://davenquinn.com/viz/corelle-demo-pbdb/?time=295)). These require composite reproductions where different parts of a feature dataset (continents) are rotated with different axis-angle transformations. I’ve had good luck doing these rotations with quaternion math in the browser/Python environments, but I am now trying to do them with Proj transformations in order to apply rotations directly within PostGIS queries.

Does anyone have suggestions on the right way to define an arbitrary spatial rotation using a Proj transformation, starting from a pole defined in Lon-lat coordinates and an associated angle of rotation around it?

I think the tool that I need is the `ob_trans` family of projections, but I have been singularly unable to define a rotation that can handle my preferred representation. Ostensibly, this is what the `o_lon_c`, `o_lat_c` and `o_alpha` parameters should do, I think, but I cannot get them to work reliably. In fact, I can’t even reliably define a ’no-op’ transformation that leaves coordinates unchanged.

Here is an example of the pl/pgsql I am currently using to assemble a projection (I have gone through many iterations of testing different offsets etc.):

```
RETURN '+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_alpha=' || pi()/2+angle || 'r +o_lon_c=' || pi()/2+lon || 'r +o_lat_c=' || lat || 'r' proj
```

Where (lat, lon, angle) defines a rotation pole.

This results in some geometries (with a fortuitous set of poles, I guess) attaining ballpark-correct transformations while other features are shifted far outside of their destination tiles.

[image: Partially reprojected continents]